# Using google map inside iframe on my website

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-2

I would like to use google maps in my website via iframe, but how can i use this link https://www.google.fr/maps/@... in my iframe. My goal is to access and use all functions of google maps directly on my website. I mean, have access to menu and others options like in my screenshot ->

[image]

Comment: Why not just use their maps api and embed a map instead of putting it in an iframe?

Comment: my goal is to use the menu of google maps, login and use share my position .... it's not to show a simple position !!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question that made me search to find out whether that feature you requested is part of the API. It's not, but they do have a workaround which utilizes Javascript and allows you to embed a search box with the autocomplete functionality. Personally I think that's even better because you can completely control the appearance of that search form.

Here's the link to the example code: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Edit: Just saw your comment. I guess this answer only addresses one issue then.

Comment: nice but my goal is to have menu of google maps like in my screen, only API allow that

Answer (score -2):

You can also put it in an popup. Look at this code:

```
<a href="" target="popup" onclick="popupCenter('//maps.google.com/maps?q=+London, +Downingstreet 10, +England','Locatie',600,610)" title="Locatie"><img src="images/pin-google.png" height="15" alt="googlemaps" title="View our address in Google Maps" /></a>
```

The iframecode:

```
<iframe src="http//maps.google.com/maps?q=+London, +Downingstreet 10, +England" height="610" width="600"></iframe>
```

Comment: it will change anything in my case ;)